# Consulta sql: Obtener roles que no le pertenecen a un usuario

Tags: sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
La tabla usuarios con el campo Id
La tabla rol con el campo Id_rol
La tabla enlace con el campo Id_user y Id_rol

En la tabla usuarios tengo insertado a "pedro"
En la tabla rol tengo insertado "admin","usuario","moderador"
En la tabla enlace tengo insertado "pedro","usuario"
```

Quiero obtener los ROLES **que no le pertenecen** al usuario **"pedro"**

He intentado mediante la siguiente consulta sql pero no consigo obtener el resultado adecuado:

```
SELECT ID_ROL
FROM enlacerole,usuariodef1
WHERE enlacerole.ID_USER=usuariodef1.CORREO and CORREO='pedro@'

union

SELECT ID_ROL
FROM roledef1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver mediante `LEFT JOIN`

[SQL - Left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

El left join trae todas las filas de la tabla de la izquierda además de las que satisfacen la condición de join. Para los que no la satisfacen agrega valores `null` en las columnas de la tabla de la derecha.

A ti lo que te interesa es tener en cuenta solo cuando el usuario es 'pedro' y a su vez obtener las filas donde no hay matcheo con la tabla `ENLACE`, por lo que puedes obtener primero los enlaces de pedro y luego tener en cuenta solo las tuplas que id_usuario sea nulo para obtener los roles que no pertenecen a pedro.

**Solución:**

```
select * from rol left join (select * from enlace where id_user='pedro') as enlacespedro 
on (enlacespedro.id_rol = rol.id_rol) 
where id_user is null;
```

He creado un caso de prueba aquí: [SQL demo roles](http://tpcg.io/HgOJ19):

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

Por SQL yo te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
Select * from Rol
WHERE 
   IdRol Not IN ( 
                  Select IdRol 
                  From Enlace 
                  Where 
                     IdUsr IN (Select IdUsr From Usuario WHERE Usuario='pedro')  
                )
```

Aclaro que estoy usando `Usuario` como nombre de la columna donde tiene el datos comparar, en tu ejemplo pones que insertas `pedro` y luego buscas `pedro@` así que aplicalo según realmente corresponda.

Comment: No te preocupes por la sintaxis de las columnas , de eso me encargo yo, gracias por tu tiempo, pero la consulta aunque sintacticamente está bien, no devuelve campos :(